# Get the complete month name in English

Tags: c#, datetime

I use `DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM")` in order to get the current month's full name. It works well, but I get it in *Hebrew*.
Is there an option to control the output language?
I need it to be *English*.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can pass a `CultureInfo` object as an argument `DateTime.ToString()`:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", ci);

// alternatively you can use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture:
var month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 24):

Pass in the culture in which you want the name formatted. Like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Answer (score 18):

An alternative option to the ones given by other posters:

```
int month = DateTime.Now.Month;

// Or use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture if you want
CultureInfo usEnglish = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTimeFormatInfo englishInfo = usEnglish.DateTimeFormat;
string monthName = englishInfo.MonthNames[month - 1];
```

I'm not saying it's better or worse than anything else - just an alternative.

Comment: This is most useful when you have the month number but not an actual DateTime object to begin with. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

you can use `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureName)` to get month name in different languages.

Refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.createspecificculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

Creates a [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) that represents the specific culture that is associated with the specified name.

```
string MonthName =  DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureName));
```

For a list of predefined culture names, see the [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx) at the Go Global Developer Center

```
//    CULTURE                                              SPECIFIC CULTURE
//                 Invariant Language (Invariant Country)  
//    af           Afrikaans                               af-ZA
//    am           Amharic                                 am-ET
//    ar           Arabic                                  ar-SA
//    arn          Mapudungun                              arn-CL
//    as           Assamese                                as-IN
//    az           Azerbaijani                             az-Latn-AZ
//    az-Cyrl      Azerbaijani (Cyrillic)                  az-Cyrl-AZ
//    az-Latn      Azerbaijani (Latin)                     az-Latn-AZ
//    ba           Bashkir                                 ba-RU
//    be           Belarusian                              be-BY
//    bg           Bulgarian                               bg-BG
//    bn           Bengali                                 bn-IN
//    bo           Tibetan                                 bo-CN
//    br           Breton                                  br-FR
//    bs           Bosnian                                 bs-Latn-BA
//    bs-Cyrl      Bosnian (Cyrillic)                      bs-Cyrl-BA
//    bs-Latn      Bosnian (Latin)                         bs-Latn-BA
//    ca           Catalan                                 ca-ES
//    co           Corsican                                co-FR
//    cs           Czech                                   cs-CZ
//    cy           Welsh                                   cy-GB
//    da           Danish                                  da-DK
//    de           German                                  de-DE
//    dsb          Lower Sorbian                           dsb-DE
//    dv           Divehi                                  dv-MV
//    ...
//    ta           Tamil                                   ta-IN
//    te           Telugu                                  te-IN
//    tg           Tajik                                   tg-Cyrl-TJ
//    tg-Cyrl      Tajik (Cyrillic)                        tg-Cyrl-TJ
//    th           Thai                                    th-TH
//    tk           Turkmen                                 tk-TM
//    tn           Setswana                                tn-ZA
//    tr           Turkish                                 tr-TR
//    tt           Tatar                                   tt-RU
//    tzm          Tamazight                               tzm-Latn-DZ
//    tzm-Latn     Tamazight (Latin)                       tzm-Latn-DZ
//    ug           Uyghur                                  ug-CN
//    uk           Ukrainian                               uk-UA
//    ur           Urdu                                    ur-PK
//    uz           Uzbek                                   uz-Latn-UZ
//    uz-Cyrl      Uzbek (Cyrillic)                        uz-Cyrl-UZ
//    uz-Latn      Uzbek (Latin)                           uz-Latn-UZ
//    vi           Vietnamese                              vi-VN
//    wo           Wolof                                   wo-SN
//    xh           isiXhosa                                xh-ZA
//    yo           Yoruba                                  yo-NG
//    zh           Chinese                                 zh-CN
//    zh-CHS       Chinese (Simplified) Legacy             zh-CN
//    zh-CHT       Chinese (Traditional) Legacy            zh-HK
//    zh-Hans      Chinese (Simplified)                    zh-CN
//    zh-Hant      Chinese (Traditional)                   zh-HK
//    zu           isiZulu                                 zu-ZA
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the overload that takes a `IFormatProvider`:

```
  CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
  DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", culture));
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

You can either set the culture of the thread:

```
  DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
  // Sets the CurrentCulture property to U.S. English.
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
  // Displays dt, formatted using the ShortDatePattern
  // and the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.
  Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MMMM"));
```

Or you can pass a `CultureInfo` to the `DateTime.ToString()` function.

```
  // Creates a CultureInfo for U.S. English.
  CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
  // Displays dt, formatted using the ShortDatePattern
  // and the CultureInfo.
  Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MMMM", ci));
```

Note that you could also choose [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx).