# Time format C# - prevent month being converted to native language

Tags: c#, date

When I display the name of the month in web , the name is being converted to native language settings. Is there a way to keep the english name of the month?

Example :

[image]

(the highlighted word is January in hebrew )

And I want it actually being shown as 'January' , here is the code of the formatting

```
productDetails.ArrivalDate.ToString("MMMM d yyyy");
```

Comment: Can you not pass the culture you want?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711390/get-the-complete-month-name-in-english help?

Comment: Amazing , everything is already asked .... I need to do more homework before asking ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
productDetails.ArrivalDate.ToString("MMMM d yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to enforce culture info

```
productDetails.ArrivalDate.ToString("MMMM d yyyy" , new CultureInfo("en-us"));
```

Comment: What's wrong with this? Why is it voted down? Except for the culture  being `"en-us"` instead of `"en-US"`.

Comment: thanks for your interest and in my code I used `"en-us"` and worked correclty